# Create a new Tenant in sitelink using API

Tags: php, api

```
<?php

define( 'SITELINK_URL', "https://www.smdservers.net/CCWs_3.5/CallCenterWs.asmx?WSDL");
define( 'SITELINK_CORP_CODE', "CCTST" );
define( 'SITELINK_LOC_CODE', "Demo" );
define( 'SITELINK_CORP_LOGIN', "Administrator" );
define( 'SITELINK_CORP_PASS', "Demo" );


$client = new SoapClient( SITELINK_URL );
$params = new stdClass; // as stdClass
$params = array("sCorpCode" => SITELINK_CORP_CODE,"sLocationCode" =>SITELINK_LOC_CODE,"sCorpUserName" => SITELINK_CORP_LOGIN,"sCorpPassword" => SITELINK_CORP_PASS,"First_name" => "Rahul","Last_name" => "Singh");

try
{
$tenant = $client->TenantNew($params);
$tenantResult = $tenant->TenantNewResult->any;
}
catch (Exception $e )
{
    die( 'Error: '.$e->getMessage().'<br>'.$e );
}
  echo htmlentities($tenantResult);

?>
```

Trying to create a new Tenant using above code but it returns (-99) which is a General exception. 
What I am doing wrong in the above code. Also on success I need to do reservation using ReservationNew method. Please help on this. Thanks

Comment: I don't know what Sitelink is, but if it's returning an error code, it should have a manual that explains the error code.

Comment: Sitelink is a storage software visit the site for more details http://www.sitelink.com/ I am receiving an error code -99 for above code which the documentation says is a General exception, nothing more than that.Want to make sure all parameters are right.

Comment: I believe SoapClient expects your $params to be a class. You start out defining it as a stdClass, but then you assign it an array.  This is likely the problem.

[code]
$params->sCorpCode = SITELINK_CORP_CODE;
$params->sLocationCode = SITELINK_LOC_CODE;
$params->sCorpUserName = SITELINK_CORP_LOGIN;
$params->sCorpPassword = SITELINK_CORP_PASS;
$params->sFirstName = "Rahul";
$params->sLastName = "Singh";[/code]

Answer (score 1):

here's code that "worked"*.  I looked into the WSDL file to see the names they used for the various params and changed "first_name" and "last_name" to "sTenantFirstName" and "sTenantLastName"

*by "worked" I mean it gave what looks like a more meaningful response, and not just an error code

reference: https://www.smdservers.net/CCWs_3.5/CallCenterWs.asmx?WSDL

```
<?php

define( 'SITELINK_URL', "https://www.smdservers.net/CCWs_3.5/CallCenterWs.asmx?WSDL"); 
define( 'SITELINK_CORP_CODE', "CCTST" );
define( 'SITELINK_LOC_CODE', "Demo" );
define( 'SITELINK_CORP_LOGIN', "Administrator" );
define( 'SITELINK_CORP_PASS', "Demo" );

$client = new SoapClient( SITELINK_URL );
$params->sCorpCode = SITELINK_CORP_CODE;
$params->sLocationCode = SITELINK_LOC_CODE;
$params->sCorpUserName = SITELINK_CORP_LOGIN;
$params->sCorpPassword = SITELINK_CORP_PASS;
$params->sTenantFirstName = "Rahul";
$params->sTenantLastName = "Singh";

try
{
    $tenant = $client->TenantNew( $params );
    $tenantResult = $tenant->TenantNewResult->any;
}
catch (Exception $e ) {
    die( 'Error: '.$e->getMessage().'<br>'.$e ); 
}

echo htmlentities($tenantResult);  

?>
```

Comment: I have been using the Sitelink API for a few years and the solution @fbas gave should work. I assume you are using the Sitelink API documentation. It is not always perfect, so I use SoapUI hit the API first to make sure the param fields are correct. As fbas pointed out, it should be sTenantFirstName, and sTenantLastName. Also, note that you will need to make sure the Corporate Username has the correct permissions set up in Corporate Control and you have an API access key that you are passing through in the request.